# Converting a probability density function into its Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I have the following probability density function

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 4x & \mbox{for }0< x < 1/2 \\ 4-4x & \mbox{for }1/2 \leq x < 1 & \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I am tasked to now find its probability distribution function in the same piece wise format. I have the solution to this problem however I do not really understand the solution.

The solution is the integral from 0 to x of 4x(for the first interval of 
0 < x<= 1/2)+ integral of 0 to 1/2 of 4x + integral of 1/2 to x of 4-4x(for the second interval).

I understand the first interval but I am stumped as to why we add the integral of 0 to 1/2 of 4x to the integral of 1/2 to x for the second interval.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want the cumulative probability, there is a probability of $\int_0^{1/2} 4x \, dx =\frac12$ of being $\frac12$ or less, which you have to add to the probability of being from $\frac12$ up to the value you are interested in

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is asking for the CDF.
It's hard to tell what you are writing since you didn't format.

Essentially, it should be

$$F_X(x) = P(X\leq x)=\begin{cases}
0& x<0\\
\int_0^x 4t\,dt& 0\leq x< \frac{1}{2}\\
\int_0^{1/2} 4t\,dt+\int_{1/2}^x4-4t\,dt&\frac{1}{2}\leq x <1\\
1& x\geq 1\end{cases}$$

Loosely speaking, this is the case because the CDF is the accumulation of probability (area) under the curve **up to** $x$.

Comment: So x is always defined as the point at which we are accumulating to then? As I am confused when to include actual integers as the end points vs the variable x. That is I am confused as what x is when talking about the area under the curves of these functions.

Comment: This is an odd example to try to understand from. Take instead $X$ to follow a continuous unif(0,1). The cdf of $X$ is $$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x) = \int_0^xf_X(t)\,dt = \int_0^x 1\,dt = x$$ when $0\leq x < 1$. Does this help? Do you see that this is the area under the curve $f_X(x)$ up to $x$?

Comment: So x is really the end point of a specific interval? So if it was a piece wise from 0 to lets say 5 for f1(x) and 5 to 10 for f2(x) you would add from 0 to x for the first interval then from 5 onward to x for the next interval?

Comment: I believe that is correct. It would be easier to tell if you format. But, yes naively speaking the cdf $F_X(x)  =P(X\leq x)$ is the "area to the left" under the pdf. To see this using a piecewise function, use your current exercise. Graph the pdf, and notice that if $0\leq x <\frac{1}{2}$, then the area to the left of $x$ is the first intergal I provided. If $\frac{1}{2}\leq x<1$, then the area to the left of $x$ is the sum of integrals I provided.

Comment: Perfect thank you. And yes I realize I'm not formatting correctly but I think I get it. You've been a big a help. I am starting to get it in a 1d environment but I soon have to look at it in a 2d environment(joint pdf's). May have more questions on this later that you may see on here haha.

Comment: By the way, awesome user name haha.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks. I would say likewise if your username was 'JmaxC' (my name is Max) :p Good luck.

Comment: Hi again Max.. I just realized a weird thing about this problem. It seems the x may be the probability not the random variable. As if for example if you input 1/3 in for f(x) it will fall under the 4x category which gives 4/3 which is >1(thus not a probability). How is this possible?

Comment: @JmanxC That's not a problem; it is actually reasonably common. $~$ Probability *density* values *may* be greater than $1$; they are only required to be *non-negative*. $~$ They are not probability *masses* but, naively, "rates of change" of the cumulative probability. $~ ~ f(1/3)=3/4$ just means the cumulative distribution is increasing with a steep gradient at that point.  The cumulative distribution is $F(1/3)=2/9$.

Comment: So the cumulative probability function(F(x))for continuous RV's does output probabilities(ie: P(X<=x) ) but the density function does not? Sort of confused as to what the probability density function is used for then. Like if we were to put it into context of an everyday statistics problem, what would the density function tell us?

Comment: @Graham Kemp To note I do understand that the probabilities are found by finding the area under the curve of f(x) but what I do not understand is what the Y values(ie the output) on the f(x) graph represent

Comment: @JmanxC Hi, I was away from the computer. Basically $F$ is a function that when you input a value, it spits out the $p$th percentile. For example, consider $X$ that follows a standard normal distribution. We know that the median is $0$, mean half of the probability falls below $0$ and half above. You can check this by using $F$; $F_X(0) = \Phi(0) = .5$, which means $0$ is the $50$th percentile.

Comment: @JmanxC As for density, [here is a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654217/pdf-is-defined-as-f-xx-px-x-but-isnt-px-x-0). we recently answer regarding density. It might also help to skim through the [this page](http://mathinsight.org/probability_density_function_idea), for simply google 'probability density'.

Comment: @JmanxC The slope of the curve $y=F(x)$ is $y'=f(x)\quad$  (at least where $F(x)$ is increasing smoothly). $~$ It provides us with information about the shape of the distribution; which in turn can be used to evaluate expected values, variance, skewness, entropy, &c.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding the concept around density functions(ie the X-->Y relationship and mapping) .If we are thinking of a normal distribution as probablyme brought up I understand percentiles come about when you consider the area under the curve but what I still do not understand even after reading that particular example on this site is what the the relationship between x and y are in a density function.

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question but what I am getting at is if we are talking about normal distribution, how does one map out a normal curve? What are the X values you are inputting to get Y values to make that curve and what are the relationships between them?.Or maybe I am thinking in the wrong way,maybe the density function comes from the distribution function when statisticians gather data?(ie to see the distribution functions behavior, is that what you meant @Graham Kemp ?). Any last input on this would be appreciated but it looks like I need to do some serious reading lol

Comment: @Jmanxc The Normal Distribution's pdf is the classic "Bell Curve".  The area under the curve up to a point ($x$) is the cumulative distribution.  Plotting this gives a sigmoidalike curve.  The gradient of this S-shaped curve is the probability density. Plotting this gives the classic "Bell Curve".

Comment: @JmanxC I might help to continue working on problems and you'll digest it that way. I think there other thing you are getting at is the difference between probability and inference. I think it will become clearer as you continue your studies.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$f(x) =\begin{cases} 4x & \mbox{for }0< x < 1/2 \\ 4-4x & \mbox{for }1/2 \leq x < 1 & \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then you want to find

$$F(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{for } x\leq 0  \\[1ex] \int_0^x 4s\operatorname d s & \mbox{for }0< x < 1/2 \\[1ex] \int_0^{1/2} s\operatorname d s + \int_{1/2}^x 4-4s\operatorname d s & \mbox{for }1/2 \leq x < 1 & \\[1ex] 1 & \mbox{for } 1\leq x\end{cases}$$

Comment: You read my mind :p

Comment: Hi Graham I have left a comment for @probablyme above(the last comment) which you may be able to answer as well as I know you have helped me with a few questions on this site.